# hot to set tinymce.init in django-tinymce package

Tags: python, django, tinymce, tinymce-4

I can't use CDN of tinymce in my project.
So I wanna use django-tinymce package.
But don't know how to set tinymce.init
to set my personal configuration.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the doc for django-tinymce. There is a whole section discussing configuration, including customizing the tinymce.init() config object:
https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#configuration

Comment: but this doc is not enouth for what i want. i've checked it recently.